# Passing named groups via url via a decorator to a view using RequestFactory

Tags: python, django

I have a url :

```
url(r'^p4_users/can_access/(?P<user>[a-zA-Z\.0-9]+)$', 'p4_audit.views.user_can_access')
```

Which will access a view:

```
def user_can_access(request, user=None, p4=None):
```

Via a decorator:

```
def p4_login_required(f):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        import re
        if re.search("p4_users/can_access", request.META['PATH_INFO']):
            import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            try:
                p4 = P4.P4()
                p4.port = settings.P4_SERVER
                p4.user = str(request.user.username)
                p4.connect()
                p4.run_login("-s")
                kwargs['p4'] = p4
                return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
            except P4Exception:
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/login")
            except Exception as e:
                return HttpResponse(e)
    return wrapper
```

Test:

```
@pytest.mark.user_brett_can_access
def test_brett_can_access(self, p4_conn, create_all, rf):
    request = rf.get("p4_users/can_access/brett.bates")
    request.user = User.objects.get(username="brett.bates")
    response = user_can_access(request)
```

But when I access this via a RequestFactory pointing to ("/p4_users/can_access/brett.bates"), the p4 variable get's passed fine, but the user variable is None (as the default is). Any ideas as to why?

(Let me know if i can provide more info)

Thanks in advance,

Brett

Comment: In your pdb shell, what is the content of `args` and `kwargs`? Does it still contain the user at that point?

Comment: forgot to remove that pdb statement, but good point. args = (), kwargs = {}

Comment: It seems the url it is suffering some change internally. Try adding an optional slash `/` at the end of the url pattern.

Comment: Same issue. Is there any way to test what is happening within urls.py, and what it is finding to pass on to the specified view?

Comment: You can use your existing pdb hook and look at the different stack frames and their local variables; pdb commands `bt`, `up`, and `print locals()` should help

Comment: going up through the frames doesn't help the one above is the actual test. Which i should really add:
*moved to actual question*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are directly calling the `user_can_access` function, and you are not passing the `user` argument. There is no magic in place that populates the `kwargs`, and using the request factory, the url conf is completely bypassed. If you want to test the whole thing, from urlconf down to the view, use the test client instead (code here for a method of a Django TestCase, [might need adjustment](http://pytest-django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/helpers.html#id1) for your setup):

```
def test_brett_can_access(self):
    resp = self.client.get("/p4_users/can_access/brett.bates")
    # self.assertContains(resp, "...") etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view is expecting `user` be passed as an keyword argument, but you aren't providing it in the decorator when callin `f`. You code should be like this:

```
def p4_login_required(f):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        import re
        if re.search("p4_users/can_access", request.META['PATH_INFO']):
            import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            try:
                p4 = P4.P4()
                p4.port = settings.P4_SERVER
                p4.user = kwargs['user'] #  You want to check the user param given by the url, right?
                p4.connect()
                p4.run_login("-s")
                kwargs['user'] = p4.user  # Function f (the view) is expecting this
                kwargs['p4'] = p4
                return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
            except P4Exception:
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/login")
            except Exception as e:
                return HttpResponse(e)
    return wrapper
```

Comment: The user variable should be coming from the url. From ?P<user> in the url Regex. P4.user is the perforce user making the request and is used elsewhere.

Comment: What url are you using for test?

Comment: request = rf.get("p4_users/can_access/brett.bates")

Comment: rf being an rf fixture from py.test django, which i believe just creates a standard django requestfactory object